# Button loading same information repeatedly instead of once (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, button, bar-chart

I am trying to load data from SQL Server onto a bar graph.That has been achieved, however when I click the 'load' button the graph is plotted directly proportional to the number of clicks.I want one click to load data on weekly basis only and other clicks to simply refresh and not falsely plot on other week(s).

One click,desired output.[image: Desired display].

Two clicks and so on should just refresh the graph

[image: Second clicks],

[image: Third click]

etc but I am getting these results.

Here is the load button code:

```
private void Load_BTN_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            string selectQuery = "SELECT  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, Date), 0) AS month, SUM(Fuel_Amount) AS Expr1 FROM Fuel_Attendend GROUP BY DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, Date), 0)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    this.chart1.Series["Fuel_Amount"].Points.AddY(dr.GetInt32(1));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

`
And this is the table:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `this.chart1.Series["Fuel_Amount"].Points` have methods on it other than `AddY`? `Clear` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is you clear the chart1 Series
and then add the Fuel_Amount Series

As Shown in the below code.

```
   private void Load_BTN_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
       this.chart1.Series.Clear();
       this.chart1.Series.Add("Fuel_Amount");
        string selectQuery = "SELECT  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, Date), 0) AS month, SUM(Fuel_Amount) AS Expr1 FROM Fuel_Attendend GROUP BY DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, Date), 0)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                this.chart1.Series["Fuel_Amount"].Points.AddY(dr.GetInt32(1));

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This will make the chart to refresh on the button click.

Also I would also suggest you to use Using block when you are dealing with SqlCommand and Connection.